# CSS and regex (?)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was wondering is there way to do something like regex replace in css file?

For example: i have lot of selectors like these:

```css
 #div_23
 #div_45
 #div_8
```

Let's say that i cant use classes to add styling, is there way to do something like this in CSS file:

```css
 #div_[0-9] {background:#000000}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can partly match attributes ([css2.1 doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) / [css3 doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)) - note however that these rules are rather slow. Especially in your case, where you have to use ultra-slow attribute selectors to match ids which would be blazing fast when using `#`.

I prefer using hyphenated Ids and classes, I find them more readable and this way you can use the following matcher:

```css
[att|=val]
```

Applied to your case:

```css
#div-23
#div-45
#div-8
#div
```

would all match

```css
[id|=div]{background:#000000}
```

However, CSS3 provides the following attribute selector (which is supported in all major browsers) which would suit your case perfectly:

```css
[att^=val]
```

so you could write:

```css
[id^=div_]{background:#000000}
```

to match

```css
#div_23
#div_45
#div_8
/* and */
#div_
```

Comment: "less supported" That's no argument in this case: It's supported in all major browsers (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Browser_compatibility). May I ask for a source to back up the statement " `[att^=val]` is slower than `[att|=val]`"?

Comment: @RobW 1) major browsers - what's this? IE7,8 or only 9, Firefox 13 or 3.5, ... ?? There are people who still have to support "old" browsers. 2) "might" - it was only an assupmtion because it's a more general expression

Comment: I added that [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Browser_compatibility) for some reason... IE7+, FF 1+ (and be realistic, few users use Firefox 3.5 any more, although 3.6 is still commonly used). `[att^=val]` is **not** a RegEx, it's a substring match (a regex would have to be parsed first, a substring to look at index zero is not very expensive).

Comment: @RobW go to China - 20% marketshare on IE6, take some companies - 100% IE6. And I wasn't regarding to that link but your general statement "major browsers". It's a fact, that it's less supported taking all browsers currently still in usage into account. And might be even slower was regarding to the higher expressiveness which in theory **might** be slower. If you think I'm incorrect feel free to downvote me or make an edit which fits your needs.

Comment: The fact that 21.3% of the China users ([reference!](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)) still use IE6 does **not** mean that many users of *your* site are using IE6. At the same graph, you see that the IE6 usage in most countries is well below 1%. If you don't believe that graph, have a look at other sources such as [GetClicky](http://www.getclicky.com/marketshare/global/web-browsers/internet-explorer/) or [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201106-201206) (at StatCounter IE6 doesn't even appear any more, because of the minimal use of IE6).

Comment: Leaving the IE6 discussion, to get back to the original statement: "`[att^=val]` is less supported than `[att^=val]`" is incorrect. IE6 doesn't support any attribute selector.

Comment: Since when were attribute selectors "ultra-slow", and what happened today that made people so up in arms about IE6 on this site? Let's just say that CSS2.1 and CSS3 attribute selectors all share the same level of support by IE version: none at all in IE6, all the same bugs in IE7, and full stable support in IE8+.

Comment: It doesn't matter who's visiting my site, it matters who visits SomeoneS's site. It's not a question of I believe you or not. Personally I couldn't care less about IE6+7 users, but we do have a chinese client at work. Who knows how SomeoneS's situation looks like? I've corrected my answer to please your strict requirements;)

Comment: @BoltClock attribute selectors sure are slower then id-selectors. It's even worse if they are unqualified. Take a look at the [perfection kills article](http://perfectionkills.com/profiling-css-for-fun-and-profit-optimization-notes/). "Super Slow" and "Blazing Fast" sure were some sort of hyperbole.

Answer (score 4):

try `[id^=div_]` this should help

Comment: [id^=div_] would be more correct. To clarify for the OP, this is an attribute selector, so it replaces the #div_ part entirely. See http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/

Comment: Ok, but how to use this: ` #div_[id^=div_] {} ` or just ` [id^=div_] {} `

Comment: @SomeoneS it would be the latter one. But look at my answer, it's very slow and should be avoided wherever you can. Also it's css3 and not that well supported.

Comment: This answer is correct (the other answer forces the prefix to be `div-`, although the OP showed that the prefix was `div_`). The statement about the performance of `^=` is ungrounded, so I'd take that with a grain of salt.